# Errors when compiling wxWidgets

Tags: makefile, codeblocks, wxwidgets

I'm following [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/803106/Introduction-to-wxWidgets-GUI-programming-with-wxS) tutorial to begin with Code::Blocks using wxWidgets.

Following the tutorial, my first step was:

```
cd C:\wxWidgets-3.0.3\build\msw
```

Since I have the **mingw32-make.exe** installed in the directory **C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin**, next I do the following (again based on the tutorial):

```
C:\wxWidgets-3.0.3\build\msw>"C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin\mingw32-make" -f makefile.gcc BUILD=release SHARED=0 MONOLITHIC=1 UNICODE=1 CXXFLAGS=-fno-keep-inline-dllexport
```

The output I get is:

```
gcc -c -o gcc_mswu\wxregex_regcomp.o  -O2 -mthreads  -DHAVE_W32API_H -DNDEBUG -I
..\..\include -I..\..\lib\gcc_lib\mswu -D__WXMSW__  -D_UNICODE   -MTgcc_mswu\wxr
egex_regcomp.o -MFgcc_mswu\wxregex_regcomp.o.d -MD -MP ../../src/regex/regcomp.c

gcc: error: CreateProcess: No such file or directory
makefile.gcc:5702: recipe for target 'gcc_mswu\wxregex_regcomp.o' failed
mingw32-make: *** [gcc_mswu\wxregex_regcomp.o] Error 1
```

I think that gcc is not found, so I need to edit the makefile.gcc

Am I right?

I'm not used to makefiles, so, I apologize but I need some help.

Comment: You don't need to edit the makefile. Is there such a
program as `C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin\gcc` and
is `C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin` in your `PATH`,
so that `gcc` will be found there?

Comment: @MikeKinghan, as you can see in my question the error reports: 
"gcc: error: CreateProcess: No such file or directory"  

So gcc is there but can't find a file or directory. 

I don't know wich file or directory is.

Comment: @user8254640, could you please post the content of the $PATH variable?

Comment: @MikeKinghan, I misunderstood your previous comment. You tell me to set the PATH to C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin. Now I did that and I'm going to do the compiling. Let's see what I can do.

Comment: No, check if `C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin` is in your `PATH` and if not, *add* it to your `PATH`

Answer (score 0):

Open a command box and `cd C:\wxWidgets-3.0.3\build\msw`

Type and press enter:

`PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin`

This will add the mingw needed files (they execute chained) to your PATH, only for the command box. If you want it permanent, modify `PATH`enviroment var in you Windows settings.

Now run the command to compile wxWidgets:

`mingw32-make" -f makefile.gcc BUILD=release SHARED=0 MONOLITHIC=1 UNICODE=1 CXXFLAGS="-std=gnu++11"` The `std=gnu+11` flag is default (not needed) if your mingw version uses gcc >=5.2. Use it anyhow, it's harmless.

Adding `RUNTIME_LIBS=static` may avoid to have a couple of mingw libs visible (on the path). This way you can run your app without providing those libs.

Probably you'll get zillions of warnings (not errors) about "deprecating" with BestSize. That's a gcc <5.3 bug, not wx one.

You can get rid of those messages modifying a few lines at `include/wx/window.h` But better don't use the old version that ships with CB and download the newest one from http://www.mingw.org/

Comment: In addition to what Rip2 said: you better compile with `BUILD=debug` to be able to do debugging of your code alone with wxWidgets.

Comment: To be precise, `BUILD=debug` make possible to debug **inside** wxWidgets code.

Comment: @Rip2, agreed. Also, why do you suggest `MONOLITHIC=1 UNICODE=1`. The latter should be on ON by default - it is 3.0 and the former is not recommended as it usually creates problems.

Comment: @Igor I just copied most of the OP's command. `UNICODE=1`is default on wx3.0 yes. And I don't like `MONOLITIC=1`because it slows down each compilation of an app a lot, but it's easier for starters, less libs to add to the project.

Comment: @Rip2, OK, I see now. It just weird that people try to compile the library and they don't know/understand fully what each option will do for them.

Comment: @Rip2, see https://forums.wxwidgets.org/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=43634&p=178225#p178225 for a reference on MONOLITHIC vs NON-MONOLITHIC build

Comment: @Igor Good to know. THX. So MONOLITHIC does not work with the provided samples, but works with my own app, right?

Comment: Yes. I don't know why it is still supported. ;-)